# Is there a way to specify a post condition using resharper attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes, resharper, static-analysis

Say we have a method

```
internal static void NotNull<T>(T value)
    where T : class
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell Resharper's static analysis that a value passed to this method is never null after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that:

```
[JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotation("halt <= null")]
public void NotNull(object obj)
{
  // ...
}
```

and an extension method like

```
[JetBrains.Annotations.NotNull]
public static T NotNull<T>(this T obj)
{
  // ...
  return obj;
}
```

Personally I like the second more, because it's fluent and you can just continue with your code :)